# Replacing fragments dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Now I know this is a very simple question and was asked many times, but non of the solutions provided previously has worked for me.

I have an activity with a FrameLayout as follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/replace_me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And in my MainActivity class I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        replaceFragment(new ChooseLevelFragment(), false);
    }
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction replace = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.replace_me, fragment);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        replace.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    replace.commit();
    Log.d(TAG, "Fragment replaced!");
}
```

The first fragment is being shown correctly. However, when the user clicks on an item from the menu and logs in, the app should replace the current fragment with the new one

```
private void showAuthenticationDialog() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragmentByTag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(AuthenticationDialogFragment.TAG);

    if (fragmentByTag != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentByTag);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    AuthenticationDialogFragment authenticationDialogFragment = AuthenticationDialogFragment.newInstance(() -> {
        replaceFragment(new ParentControlPanelFragment(), true);
    });
    authenticationDialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, AuthenticationDialogFragment.TAG);

}
```

The new fragment is not being replaced even after the commit. I can see my log message but not the new fragment. I'm not quite sure where the problem is.

Comment: "the app should replace the current fragment with the new one" -- no, your code is showing a dialog. It has nothing to do with the previous `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: @CommonsWare after the "authentication" dialog is shown and the user clicks on the login, the "ParentControlPanelFragment" should be shown, which is not the case

Comment: Hmmm... try temporarily removing the `AuthenticationDialogFragment` and its `show()`. Try having `showAuthenticationDialog()` call `replaceFragment(new ParentControlPanelFragment(), true)` directly. If this works, then my best guess is that something about where you are using that lambda expression is the issue. If this does not work, then perhaps `ParentControlPanelFragment` has a problem (e.g., missing `onCreateView()`).

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to remove the AuthenticationDialog as you said and it worked. Now I can see the fragment. But what might be the problem in the lambda if it is calling the replace method correctly. I can see the logged message even when I have the authentication dialog showed

Comment: Your current structure might have overlapping transactions: you try replacing the `R.id.replace_me` fragment before the transaction involving the `AuthenticationDialogFragment` is completely done. Perhaps dismissing the dialog basically takes out *both* transactions: the dialog's transaction and the transaction that you tried running while inside the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to replace the fragment before I dismiss the dialog.

The correct approach is to dismiss the dialog first then try to replace the fragment.